# Assembly MASM to Change char in string from lowercase to uppercase

Tags: assembly, masm

I am writing an assembly code in MASM to convert ONLY the lowercase letters in a string already declared to uppercase, leaving the ones already uppercase alone. I have this so far  but it prints in reverse order and I don't know why. Also I am trying to remove the counter because I should not have one but without it my program does not run. Any suggestions would be helpful!

```
      .386
      .MODEL FLAT
ExitProcess PROTO NEAR32 stdcall, dwExitCode:DWORD
Include io.h                                          
cr            equ    0DH                           
Lf            equ    0AH                           
             .stack  4096
             .data
str1         dword  "aBcD",0
str1value  byte  "The new value of str1 is: ", 0 
           byte cr, Lf, 0
          .code
_start:
          sub esi, esi                            ; index reg
          lea ebx, str1
top:      mov al, [ebx+esi]
          and al, 0DFh                   ;convert lowercase to  corresponding uppercase
          mov [esi+ebx], al
          inc esi
          loop top
done:     output str1value
          output str1

          Invoke ExitProcess, 0
Public _start                                     ; make entry point public
          end                                     ; end of source code
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you've declared your string as a `dword` and how the assembler interprets `dword` string constants. You should use `byte` instead, i.e.

```
str1         byte  "aBcD",0
```

---

Also, if you use the `loop` instruction you should be initializing `cx` to the maximum number of iterations to perform. To get rid of your counter (`esi`) you could process the string backwards by using `ecx-1` as the offset to `ebx`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the reversed string is the `dword` in front of the string which should be `byte`.

To get rid of the loop counter you can simply scan the string for the 0 byte which indicates the end of the string.

```
mov esi, offset str1

@@ProcessChar:
    mov   al, [esi]
    test  al, al
    je  @@Done

    ...
    inc esi
    jmp @@ProcessChar

@@Done:
   ...
```

If you are using the loop counter approach, you have to initialize `ecx` though, which is missing in your code.